# How to extract the integer or decimal at beginning of each input line, using Linux/Unix utilities?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, awk

Given input such as:

```
1
1a
1.1b
2.0c
```

How to extract the integer/decimal number at beginning of each input line, using only Linux/Unix command line utilities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk`, you could say:

```
awk '{print $0+0}'
```

Comment: Scratch that. It will remove `0` or `0.0` if it happened to be there as well.

Comment: @jaypal That's because it would eval to 0 :)

Comment: yep, without explicit `print` line will only `print` when `true`.

Answer (score 1):

Awk is available in Linux, BSD, and many other Unix-like operating systems. It helps in this way:

```
echo "1" | awk '{a+=$0; print a}' # output 1
echo "1a" | awk '{a+=$0; print a}' # output 1
echo "1.1b" | awk '{a+=$0; print a}' # output 1.1
echo "2.0c" | awk '{a+=$0; print a}' # output 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Some more awk

For extracting only digits

```
$ awk 'gsub(/[[:alpha:]].*/,x,$1) + 1' << EOF
1
1a
1.1b
2.0c
EOF
1
1
1.1
2.0
```

For integer

```
$ awk '{print int($0)}' << EOF
1 
1a
1.1b
2.0c
EOF

1
1
1
2
```

---edit---

If there is any blank line in file, you can avoid printing zero from following

```
$ awk 'NF{$0+=0}1' << EOF
1
1a
1.1b
2foot4c

2
EOF
1
1
1.1
2

2
```

Comment: Note that the first variant would go beyond the _beginning of the line_, i.e. if a line were to read `7foo42`, then it'd produce `742`.

Comment: +1 Thanks devnull, `[[:alpha:]].*` would produce `7` now.. thanks for reporting

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do this with sed:

```
echo "12.3abc" | sed -n 's/^\([0-9.][0-9.]*\).*/\1/p'
```

Output:

```
12.3
```

The block in parentheses matches all numbers or periods '.' that occur at the beginning of the line. Everything after that is match by the '.*'.

The \1 says to replace the entire line with just the portion that was matched in the parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your version of `grep` supports `-o`:

```
grep -o '^[0-9.]\+' data.in
```

**NB**: This will match **any** sequence of digits and decimal points at the start of the line.